# Bluemix SDK can't find Finish Launching

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

where can I find the "FinishLaunchingWithOptions" method? Is it somewhere on the Dashboard provided by bluemix, or is it within the bundle of code provided by Bluemix upon creation of a new app?

And if it is within the bundle of code provided with the new app, which file can I locate it in

Comment: Try to add more context around your question next time. The info you give is far to vague for anything more than a blind stab at helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the bundle of code you are referencing is the HelloWorld app that Bluemix prompts you to download when creating a new app then the file is the AppDelegate.m for Objective C or AppDelegate.swift for Swift. Both are located in the root of their respective code repositories (so helloWorld_Swift/AppDelegate.swift).

The full method is didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and it should be the first method you will find within those source files (around lines 22-26). There's a block of comments under the method declaration that should explain the process.

Cheers